# IntelliJ: Rationale behind "Enable coverage in test folders" checkbox

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, junit, code-coverage

I have a question regarding code coverage tool in IntelliJ. Obviously, this tool was designed to run during test suite execution. Here's a screenshot of JUnit configuration window:

[image: JUnit configuration window in IntelliJ]

I am wondering when one would want to uncheck the "Enable coverage in test folders" option? When I uncheck this, I don't see any coverage results whatsoever. Since the coverage tool is run on test suits which reside in test folders, what's the rationale behind this checkbox?

Comment: Code coverage allows you to see how much of your code is being executed during unit tests, so you can understand how effective these tests are.

Comment: @y.bedrov I know, but why do I have to check this checkbox in order to see coverage results?

Comment: You need to set it if all your code is located under "test sources root"